# How do display different image based on a value

Tags: jquery

I would like to place a image on a page

```
<img src="myimage.jpeg" id="imgid" style="display:none"/>

if (PerMonth <0){
  $(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00")
  $("#imgid").css("what do i need here to display different image when <0)
;}

if (PerMonth >0){
  $(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00")
  $("#imgid").css("Display different image >0)
;}
```

Any ideas and thanks in advance

Comment: I know you are doing this in SharePoint, but you should consider moving these non SharePoint questions to the more generic StackOverflow really.

Comment: @Patrick: Questions that aren't specifically about SharePoint don't belong here. Please ask your jQuery questions elsewhere unless they demonstrate integration with SharePoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .css could use the background-image property:

http://w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Or you may want to use simply modify the .src property instead of the .css of your jquery selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

if (PerMonth <0){
  $(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00")
  $("#imgid").attr("src","image1.jpg")
;}

if (PerMonth >0){
  $(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00")
  $("#imgid").attr("src","image2.jpg")
;}